# Compiling gst-plugins-bad with SRT on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi, gstreamer, raspberry-pi3, srt

I tried to compile gst-plugins-bad with SRT, compiling was successful but I can't find the plugin. I think the dependency lib *srt* is missing and the right parameter (I used --with-srt).
These are the commands I used:

```
git clone git://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/gstreamer/gst-plugins-bad
cd gst-plugins-bad
git checkout 1.14.2
export LDFLAGS='-L/opt/vc/lib' \
CFLAGS='-I/opt/vc/include -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vcos/pthreads -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vmcs_host/linux' \
CPPFLAGS='-I/opt/vc/include -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vcos/pthreads -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vmcs_host/linux'
./autogen.sh --disable-gtk-doc --disable-examples --disable-x11 --disable-glx --disable-glx --disable-opengl --with-srt
make CFLAGS+="-Wno-error -Wno-redundant-decls -I/opt/vc/include -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vcos/pthreads -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vmcs_host/linux" \
CPPFLAGS+="-Wno-error -Wno-redundant-decls -I/opt/vc/include -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vcos/pthreads -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vmcs_host/linux" \
CXXFLAGS+="-Wno-redundant-decls" LDFLAGS+="-L/opt/vc/lib"
```

What is the right way to compile with SRT?

Answer (score 0):

You need to download and install the SRT library from https://github.com/Haivision/srt

Comment: How do I install that library, there is no make install. I don't know where I have to place which files.

Comment: There's an install section on the GitHub page. Essentially you need to install the dependenceis, then run configure and make.